# AWS Cognito custom message trigger - prevent message send

Tags: amazon-cognito

how can I prevent a message being sent from cognito custom message trigger?

Under certain circumstances, I need to skip sending welcome Email to users which usually contains the confirmation code.

Throwing an error does prevent the email from being sent, but the problem is that ìt causes the SignUpCommand to throw an error and I need the output from that function.

Answer (score 1):

Use `MessageAction: 'SUPPRESS'` in the `createUser` Function before. This will prevent sending email.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).